Which statistics are best practice for assessing the validity and reliability of a norm-based ability assessment?
I plan to assess the validity and reliability of a norm-referenced ability assessment. The instrument has 5 ability-related sub-scales. There are existing norms, but I'd like to do some additional research on a sample I have, for the purpose of adding to the body of research on the instrument.
For a criterion-referenced assessment, two of the stats I'd consider would be the Cronbach's alpha per item, and a factor analysis. Generally, would these also constitute best practice for an ability assessment?

There are several types of reliability and many types of validity. Entire books have been written about this, and some people (some of my former classmates from psychometrics, in fact) spend their time doing this.
In plain English terms, reliability is about whether a test is a "good" measure of something and validity is about whether it measures the thing you want to measure.
Just for example, there is test-retest reliability, there is face validity, content validity, and many others.
Certainly Cronbach's alpha and factor analysis could be part of your testing of validity and reliability (although there may be better alternatives to alpha) but they shouldn't be the whole of it.
